# Find the first time that two random circles meet.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems

Suppose circles 1 and 2 with radius $r_1, r_2$ and speed $v_1, v_2$ respectively are moving within a larger circle of radius $R$. Their starting position is $x_1(0), x_2(0)$.

1/ If the process is random, is there a way to quantify the first time that these two circle cross?

2/ If there is a small bias, the circle 1 has a small "incline" to move toward circle 2, is there a way to quantify this?

I apologize if this is not very clear since I am not very familiar with Stochastic process. If you know the terminology and how I could search a bit deeper on this topic, please write a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make this problem more specific by writing down the law for the stochastic process. You could do that either explicitly as a joint probability density function indexed by time $f_t(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)$, or (more likely) a system of stochastic partial differential equations to be solved, if possible, for the density at time $t$. The bias in your question (2) would be incorporated into the problem as an attraction term in this system of equations. You also have to decide what will happen if one of your circles starts drifting outside of the larger circle. This would be somewhat easier on a square, where various periodic or reflecting boundary conditions are much easier to set up, since squares can tile the plane.

You would then have to define what you mean by two circles crossing (e.g. overlap such that the intersection has positive area), then try to work out the probability $P(t)$ that the circles have not intersected by time $t$. The expected crossing time would then be the mean, $ \int_0^{\infty} t \frac{dP}{dt} dt $. There is no guarantee that this integral will be finite, though.

If you haven't done much probability or stochastic processes before, I recommend that you start with a much simpler problem: Let $a_0$, $b_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ be the starting positions of two independent simple random walks $a(t), b(t)$ on the integers (i.e. discrete time, discrete one-dimensional infinite spatial domain). Try to determine the probability distribution function $P(t)$ such that $P(t) = P( t = \min \{ t \in \mathbb{N} | a(t) = b(t) \})$.

The best reference for this stuff is William Feller, An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications, Volume 1, if you can get your hands on a copy, but any introductory text on probability or stochastic processes will do.